# JavaFX WebView add stylesheet, parsing calc error

Tags: java, html, css, webview, javafx

I'm trying to load CSS file from URL into WebView using this code: 
`this.webView.getStylesheets().add("http://page.com/style.css");` 
but JavaFX is throwing errors: 
`CSS Error parsing http://page.com/style.css: Unexpected token '-' at [230,17]` 
I checked the file, and it's calc 'method': 
`width: calc(71% - 142px);` 
Is it possible to load such page? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the stylesheet to the `WebView` itself, not to the document it is displaying. This will attempt to style the `WebView` itself: it won't apply the CSS to the HTML content. For JavaFX scene graph nodes, the `calc` function is not supported: the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) shows what CSS is valid for JavaFX scene graph nodes.

I suspect that what you are trying to do is to use the style sheet for the HTML document displayed by the `WebView`. To do that, you should reference the stylesheet in the HTML document in the usual way.

If you want to dynamically load a stylesheet, you can try manipulating the HTML document once it is loaded. Something along the following lines:

```
private void addStylesheet(Document doc, String cssLocation) {
    Element docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList heads = docElement.getElementsByTagName("head");
    Element head ;
    if (heads.getLength() == 0) {
        head = doc.createElement("head");
        docElement.appendChild(head);
    } else {
        head = (Element) heads.item(0);
    }
    Element link = doc.createElement("link");
    link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    link.setAttribute("href", cssLocation);
    head.appendChild(link);     
}
```

And then

```
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            addStylesheet(engine.getDocument(), "http://page.com/style.css");
        }
    });

    engine.load(/* your html ... */);
```

Comment: oh, thanks. I have small question about that org.w3c.dom.Node/Element, how to convert it to String with HTML?

Comment: I don't understand that question. At any rate, it looks like a different question than the one you posted, so you should ask it as a new question.